# wysiwyg summernote text editor - unable edit and save more than 700 words on the text editor

Tags: javascript, php, wysiwyg, summernote

I am using summernote text editor. First time I can add more than 700 words but I am unable edit and save more than 700 words on the text editor.

Here is the code I am using.

```
                <div class="form-group my-2">
                                            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Content</label>
                                            <textarea name="content" id="summernote"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
                                        </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
</script>
```